# Extract values from a two-dimensional list to operate with them

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am trying to extract values from a two-dimensional list, to save them and perform operations with them, in principle I get values from 3 lines 145, 154 and 157, but the problem is that I need to go through the entire list of values and extract the next 3 lines, that is, one line every 145 lines, another line every 154 lines and another line every 157 lines, so until you finish reading the entire list.

Sample of `path.dat` contents:

```
       1      1.0000  0.258309E+03   0.387369E-05   0.493390E-05
       2      2.0000  0.263808E+03   0.369658E-05   0.733094E-05
       3      3.0000  0.264706E+03   0.351946E-05   0.817271E-05
       4      5.0000  0.248739E+03   0.369658E-05   0.103040E-04
       5      7.0000  0.234918E+03   0.351946E-05   0.119915E-04
       6     10.0000  0.223707E+03   0.316522E-05   0.114943E-04
       7     20.0000  0.215601E+03   0.298810E-05   0.941933E-05
       8     30.0000  0.215591E+03   0.281098E-05   0.816810E-05
       9     50.0000  0.213185E+03   0.281098E-05   0.476642E-05
      10     70.0000  0.212209E+03   0.298810E-05   0.271009E-05
      11    100.0000  0.213632E+03   0.263386E-05   0.783644E-06
      12    125.0000  0.216840E+03   0.298810E-05   0.118827E-05
      13    150.0000  0.215781E+03   0.351946E-05   0.103647E-05
      14    175.0000  0.212525E+03   0.741608E-05   0.625855E-06
      15    200.0000  0.210277E+03   0.129068E-04   0.377638E-06
      16    225.0000  0.211308E+03   0.178661E-04   0.189399E-06
      17    250.0000  0.213660E+03   0.233568E-04   0.998937E-07
      18    300.0000  0.222232E+03   0.410687E-04   0.872060E-07
      19    350.0000  0.231604E+03   0.108728E-03   0.800548E-07
      20    400.0000  0.239510E+03   0.135473E-03   0.809775E-07
      21    450.0000  0.246600E+03   0.144506E-03   0.793627E-07
      22    500.0000  0.253364E+03   0.299663E-03   0.738263E-07
      23    550.0000  0.259311E+03   0.679052E-03   0.717501E-07
      24    600.0000  0.263732E+03   0.144970E-02   0.719808E-07
      25    650.0000  0.267508E+03   0.195502E-02   0.749797E-07
      26    700.0000  0.271180E+03   0.218368E-02   0.765945E-07
      27    750.0000  0.273655E+03   0.174336E-02   0.768252E-07
      28    775.0000  0.274527E+03   0.131243E-02   0.779786E-07
      29    800.0000  0.275410E+03   0.941542E-03   0.798241E-07
      30    825.0000  0.275755E+03   0.106978E-02   0.809775E-07
      31    850.0000  0.275817E+03   0.234202E-02   0.816696E-07
      32    875.0000  0.277539E+03   0.300675E-02   0.821309E-07
      33    900.0000  0.279860E+03   0.305316E-02   0.823616E-07
      34    925.0000  0.282089E+03   0.310133E-02   0.802855E-07
      35    950.0000  0.283788E+03   0.317501E-02   0.701353E-07
      36    975.0000  0.285004E+03   0.317767E-02   0.701353E-07
```

```py
file = open('path.dat', 'r')
```

I read the file and go to the list of lists:

```py
listA = []
for line in file.readlines():
    a = line.split()
    listA.append(a)
```

Example out `listA`:

```py
listA = [
    ['5', '0.0000', '0.9992', '0.9999', '0.9999'],
    ['6', '0.0000', '0.9986', '0.9999', '0.9999'],
    ['7', '0.0000', '0.9977', '0.9997', '0.9999'],
    ['8', '0.0000', '0.9961', '0.9992', '0.9998'],
    ['9', '0.0000', '0.9945', '0.9987', '0.9997'],
    ['10', '0.0000', '0.9928', '0.9980', '0.9995'],
    ['11', '0.0000', '0.9914', '0.9975', '0.9994'],
    ['12', '0.0000', '0.9901', '0.9972', '0.9992'],
    ['13', '0.0000', '0.9889', '0.9968', '0.9990'],
    ['14', '0.0000', '0.9877', '0.9965', '0.9988'],
    ['15', '0.0000', '0.9864', '0.9962', '0.9986'],
    ['16', '0.0000', '0.9851', '0.9959', '0.9984'],
    ['17', '0.0000', '0.9836', '0.9956', '0.9982'],
    ['18', '0.0000', '0.9813', '0.9950', '0.9978'],
    ['19', '0.0000', '0.9783', '0.9943', '0.9973'],
    ['20', '0.0000', '0.9751', '0.9936', '0.9967'],
    ['21', '0.0000', '0.9713', '0.9927', '0.9959'],
    ['22', '0.0000', '0.9673', '0.9917', '0.9949'],
    ['23', '0.0000', '0.9634', '0.9906', '0.9939'],
    ['24', '0.0000', '0.9586', '0.9894', '0.9925'],
    ['25', '0.0000', '0.9517', '0.9876', '0.9904'],
    ['26', '0.0000', '0.9408', '0.9847', '0.9866'],
    ['27', '0.0000', '0.9280', '0.9806', '0.9811'],
    ['28', '0.0000', '0.9178', '0.9769', '0.9760'],
    ['29', '0.0000', '0.9117', '0.9745', '0.9727'],
    ['30', '0.0000', '0.9022', '0.9706', '0.9673'],
    ['31', '0.0000', '0.8916', '0.9656', '0.9603'],
    ['32', '0.0000', '0.8831', '0.9610', '0.9540'],
    ['33', '0.0000', '0.8696', '0.9532', '0.9433']
]
```

With this I read a `.dat` or `.txt` file, with 60,000 lines and save it in a two-dimensional list.
To extract the values that I need I have tried the following:

```py
for i in listA:    
    line_A = listA[145] # Here I declare that I want to extract line 145
    line_B = listA[154] # Here I declare that I want to extract line 154
    line_C = listA[157] # Here I declare that I want to extract line 157
```

Here I pass the string to float type, to be able to operate with them:

```py
totalA = float(line_A[1]), float(line_A[2]), float(line_A[3])
totalB = float(line_B[1]), float(line_B[2]), float(line_B[3])
totalC = float(line_C[1]), float(line_C[2]), float(line_C[3])

print(totalA)
print(totalB)
print(totalC)

(48.47, 89.82, 101.94)
(48.37, 89.72, 101.79)
(6.17, 5.56, 8.49)

file.close()
```

In principle, I get the lines that I need, 145, 154 and 157, I move them to float to operate with their values, but I would need to extract one line every 145 lines, another line every 154 lines and so on until I read the entire list.

Comment: Did you trying slicing? Something like `listA[::145]`, `listA[::154]`, and `listA[::157]`? One  thing to keep in mind is that lists are indexed starting at 0 so you are going to get the first item on the first iteration and then  items `145`, `154`, and`157`, on the second iteration.

Comment: He tried to cut slices but it doesn't work, indexes 144, 153 and 157 are the ones that try to iterate and if they are in order they start at 0 to 60,000 lines and need iterated linear lines.

Comment: That's not the same. I'm talking about list slicing operator. Note the `::` before the steps. In other words, `every_145_rows = listA[::145]`, starting from `listA[0]`. If you want to start from row `145`, the expression must be `every_145_rows = listA[144::145]`. Does that clarifies what I'm suggesting?

Comment: I posted an possible solution. Can you post a few sample lines of `path.dat` file? I want to improve my answer a bit based on the file contents.

Comment: Your code is using columns 1, 2, and 3, as output but based on the sample posted, aren't you interested in columns 2, 3, and 4, instead?

Comment: Since the data doesn't seem to be sensitive, can you post the whole `path.dat` somewhere so I can download it and test my code on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really clear but If got it right, I guess this will achieve your goal:

```py
steps = (145, 154, 157)

with open('path.dat') as f:
    rows = f.readlines()

    for step in steps:
        # select every 'step' rows
        a = [_.strip().split() for _ in rows[step - 1::step]]

        # convert columns
        a = [[int(_[0])] + list(map(float, _[1:])) for _ in a]

        print(
            sum([_[1] for _ in a]),
            sum([_[2] for _ in a]),
            sum([_[3] for _ in a])
        )
```

Note that I'm starting counting on the `nth` element of `rows` for every slice. In other words first `145` row is, in fact, `rows[144]`. If you really want to start at `rows[145]`, replace `step - 1` with just `step`.

And here is another possible solution using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

steps = (145, 154, 157)

df = pd.read_fwf('path.dat', header=None)

for step in steps:
    # select every 'step' rows
    a = df[step - 1::step]

    print(sum(a[1]), sum(a[2]), sum(a[3]))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it a bit more? What's wrong? What's is the output from the code above, what is the expected output?

Comment: When executing your script, it returns the entire file to me in a loop, that is, it prints it as many times as it has lines.

Comment: No. It is not printing all lines from the input file. It is printing every 145th, 153th, and 157th rows from the file. Isn't that what you want? Or do you want the sum of every group? You really need to clarify that on your question. If you are looking for the sums, I can edit the code. It is trivial.

Comment: @tempoalex, check the updated answer. I guess I got it right now.